# retrieve the ID (in the database) of the element the user have clicked on a listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, android-activity, listviewitem

this is what i have done, to retrieve the id but it says that `getIndexColumn` is not defined in the cursor... what i'm doing wrong?

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
          Cursor data = (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
          String cat = Cursor.getString(Cursor.getIndexColumn(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID));

          Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sondaggioActivity.class);
          myIntent.putExtra("categoriaId", cat);
          MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }
```

**this is the category class:**

```
public class categorie {
      private long id;
      private String nome;
      private long preferita;

      public long getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public String getNome() {
        return nome;
      }

      public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
      }



      public long getPreferita() {
        return preferita;
    }

    public void setPreferita(long preferita) {
        this.preferita = preferita;
    }

    // Will be used by the ArrayAdapter in the ListView
      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return nome;
      }
    }
```

**and this is the datasource:**

```
public class pollDataSource {
    // Database fields
      private SQLiteDatabase database;
      private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
      private String[] allCategorieColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
          MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PREF, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME };   
      private String[] allSondaggiColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATID, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DOMANDA };   
      private String[] allRisposteColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, 
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SONDID, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_RISPOSTA, 
              MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SELEZIONATA };


      public pollDataSource(Context context) {
            dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
          }

      public void open() throws SQLException {
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
          }

      public void close() {
            dbHelper.close();
          }

      public categorie createCategoria(String categoria) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME, categoria);
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PREF, 0);
            long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE, null,
                values);
            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE,
                allCategorieColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            categorie newCategoria = cursorToCategorie(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return newCategoria;
          } 

      public void deleteCategoria(categorie categoria) {
            long id = categoria.getId();
            System.out.println("Categoria cancellata, id: " + id);
            database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
          }

      public sondaggi createSondaggio(String domanda, int catid) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DOMANDA, domanda);
            values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CATID, catid);
            long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI, null,
                values);
            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
                allSondaggiColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            sondaggi newSondaggio = cursorToSondaggi(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return newSondaggio;
          }


      public void deleteSondaggio(sondaggi sondaggio) {
            long id = sondaggio.getId();
            System.out.println("Sondaggio cancellato, id: " + id);
            database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
          } 

      public Cursor getAllCategorie() {
            List<categorie> categorie = new ArrayList<categorie>();

            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CATEGORIE,
                allCategorieColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
              categorie categoria = cursorToCategorie(cursor);
              categorie.add(categoria);
              cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // Make sure to close the cursor
           // cursor.close();
            return cursor;
          }


      private categorie cursorToCategorie(Cursor cursor) {
          categorie categorie = new categorie();
          categorie.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
          categorie.setPreferita(cursor.getLong(1));
          categorie.setNome(cursor.getString(2));
            return categorie;
          }
      private sondaggi cursorToSondaggi(Cursor cursor) {
          sondaggi sondaggi = new sondaggi();
          sondaggi.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
          sondaggi.setDomanda(cursor.getString(1));
          sondaggi.setCatid(cursor.getLong(2));
          return sondaggi;
          }


}
```

**the main activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
     private pollDataSource datasource;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        datasource = new pollDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        Cursor values = datasource.getAllCategorie();

        String[] categorieColumns =
            {
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NOME   // Contract class constant containing the word column name

            };


            int[] mWordListItems = { R.id.categoria_label };


        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(),               // The application's Context object
                R.layout.single_list_item,             // A layout in XML for one row in the ListView
                values,                                // The result from the query
                categorieColumns,                      // A string array of column names in the cursor
                mWordListItems,                        // An integer array of view IDs in the row layout
                0);                                    // Flags (usually none are needed)


        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }




      public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:      
        datasource.createCategoria("peppe");          


        break;          

        }





      }

      @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


          Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sondaggioActivity.class);
          myIntent.putExtra("categoriaId", id);
          MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
         //Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What is about the parameter long Id?

Comment: what type of adapter is this listview using?

Comment: i've added the mainactivity, i sue e simplecursoradapter atm, but i know the code is very very dirty, is my first app :D

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have an activity with a list of categories, and onClick of a particular item you want to launch new activity with details of that Item.
I suggest you when you launch the listScreen, query all/some items and maintaine an arrayList of items and save that in some singleton class, then onClick of a particular item pass that index to detail screen via intent.putExtra("index", position) and on detail Screen get that index via getIntent().getIntExtra("index", -1) .now get details of that particular index from arraylist saved in singleton class.
This approach will reduce cost of querying every time from database and data will be available easily.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 Cursor data = (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
 String cat = Cursor.getString(Cursor.getIndexColumn(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID));
```

to

```
 Cursor data = (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
 Long clid = data.getLong(data.getIndexColumn(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID));
 String cat=Long.toString(clid);
```

Answer (score 1):

those two lines:

```
      Cursor data = (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
      String cat = Cursor.getString(Cursor.getIndexColumn(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID));
```

makes absolutely no sense at all! If you're using a CursorAdapter why are you creating an array of objects? If you're using a ArrayAdapter why are you getting data from cursor?

Also, Cursor don't have any static methods to be called like that. That shouldn't even compile.

If you're using a CursorAdater (or some class that extend it) you the id is passed to you `long id` here `protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)`